# Get all entities from entityManager

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

Is it possible to get all the entities from EntityManager in JPA without using "Queries"?

Comment: Why do you want to do this without queries?

Comment: I'm using an Object database called Versant which has an awful and very unreliable implementation of JPA. Need to avoid JPA queries.

Comment: It's a temporary database which I have to use for now, so I can't really change the database even if I want to.